# Passing slice to Scanf

Tags: go, slice

The snippet:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    mapIsh := make([]int64, 5)
    fmt.Scanf("%v %v %v %v %v", &mapIsh[0], &mapIsh[1], &mapIsh[2], &mapIsh[3], &mapIsh[4])

    fmt.Print(mapIsh[0], mapIsh[1], mapIsh[2], mapIsh[3], mapIsh[4])
}
```

I crate a slice and want to save the contents of a read operation. The above works as expected. What i don't get is why I have to pass pointers to the array elements(I assumed the values are passed by reference for slices/arrays).

Also if I don't make one of the arguments a pointer the subsequent values wont be read. So can someone explain the following:

Input data: 1 2 3 4 5

1) For:

```
fmt.Scanf("%v %v %v %v %v", mapIsh[0], mapIsh[1], mapIsh[2], mapIsh[3], mapIsh[4])
```

I get: 0 0 0 0 0

2) For:

```
    fmt.Scanf("%v %v %v %v %v", &mapIsh[0], &mapIsh[1], mapIsh[2], &mapIsh[3], &mapIsh[4])
```

I get: 1 2 0 0 0

Comment: Add error checking. In some cases your example produce error "expected integer"

Comment: Also i've added '\n' to format string, and error disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, values are **not** passed by reference for slices/arrays.

At the same time, if you were passing a slice value to some function, the receiver would be able to modify the same underlying array, because a slice value contains a pointer.

In your case, you are not passing a slice itself, but rather copies of the dereferenced `int64` values. And `fmt.Scanf` is not updating `mapIsh`. Only passing addresses are you able to use the scanned values.

Comment: Tnx. That makes sense. I think i was confused by an example where an int was passed by reference to scanf

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are always passed by value in Go, never by reference.

You're right that passing a slice to a function would allow the function to mutate its elements.  But you're not passing a slice into `Scanf`; your two examples are passing in the int64 elements versus passing in the addresses of those elements.  I think you're getting confused by the indexing syntax and thinking `mapIsh[0]` somehow means you're passing in something the function will be able to mutate.  But `mapIsh[0]` really is just an int64, the first element of `mapIsh`.

As for why you're getting zeros, that's because Go initializes `mapIsh` to the zero-value, which for an array of int64s is all 0s.  When `Scanf` can't read into the value you forgot the `&` for, it was not able to continue.  This is why you should check the error returned from `Scanf`, which will indicate the error.

(Note that pass-by-value means that passing an array to a function creates a copy of that array, so the function will not be able to mutate the elements like it can for a slice.  That isn't actually relevant here, as described above.)

Comment: Thanks, I spaced and added "or array" without thinking.  Fixed now, and added the note at the end.